# Defending a non-idempotent post operation against being rapidly called in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

Short question: assuming a non-idempotent post operation, how do you defend your post request handlers in node.js from being called multiple times before they can respond, and hence cause data corruption?

Specific case: I have a matching API, which takes about 2-3 seconds to return (due to having to run through a large userbase). There are a number of operations where user can simply double call this within the same second (this is a bug, but not under my control, and therefore answering this part does not constitue an answer to the root question). Under these conditions, multiple matches are selected for the user, which is not desirable. Desirable outcome for this would be for all of these rapid requests to have the same end result.

Specific constrains:

- node.js / express / sequelize.
- If we add a queue, every single user's request will be on top of all other users' request, which might have drastic implications during heavy traffic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can push all your requests into a [queue](https://github.com/zackiles/bluebird-queue). In this case all your responses will have to wait for the preceding ones to finish.

The other solution is to use sequelize transactions, but that would cause `lock_wait_timeout` errors in DB.

Comment: How does that prevent double processing in the backend? The queue will contain double requests and they will all be performed eventually. Instead, the same request should never be handled more than once.

Answer (score 2):

I propose a solution where the server gracefully responds to the `same*` request and hence no changes on the client are required.

`*` First we need to establish what constitutes a request to be considered as "same". When you plan this kind of graceful, sync, response you would put a increasing counter into the clients request and this counter is the unique attribute that defines a request as `same`. But since you might not have access to the client and have no such counter you could define that requests to be the same if their `post`-body + url are the same (and could throw in that the user needs to be the same too).

So for every user you immediately save the request when it reaches your server. An easy way would be to hash the url + `post`-body, say with `SHA-256` and save it in an object like this:
`requests[user][hashOfRequest] = null`
That `null` will be replaced by a response object once your server has calculated it. Now you process the request.

If the client sends the `same*` request again you can easily find out by checking your `requests[user][hashOfRequest]`.
If the server has finished the processing it will contain a response object which you just send back to the client. If its still empty you need to wait for the processing of your server (of the first request) to finish. Maybe using an event listener or other task sync patterns.

Once the server has finished the first request it will generate the `response` and save it in `requests[user][hashOfRequest]=response` and emit the event, so that potential waiting clients will get the response too.

No more double processing and connection drops from clients, where the response does not reach them, are also handled by this pattern.

Of course you should clean up the responses hash table after a time that fits your (client) scenario. Maybe 10 minutes after the request was put into the hash table.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a [transaction](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/transactions/). 
If you put all of your SQL commands into a transaction, I think the requests will be separated.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I've settled on eventually was a variation on @Festo's general approach, as follows:

- adding a unique key constraint for the matches
- Each parallel requests attempts to create a new match; all but the first one will fail to do so due to the constraint
- if the constraint insert fails, app just pulls the match already in the database, adds it to the rest of the matches, and returns it

This makes it impossible to spam-create new matches via rapidly calling the API. However, I am not satisfied with this, on account of this approach not generalizing to eg: non-deterministic idempotent operations (eg if the matches would be generated randomly, consequent calls would return different matches, and therefore a simple constraint check would be insufficient).

All my internet points for an answer which does not requre client-side ticket management (@Sushant), nor queues, and can handle non-deterministic idempotent functions.

Answer (score -1):

Under my APIs I use [express-jwt](https://github.com/auth0/express-jwt) and token based authentication for all REST authentication. I keep these tokens valid for only one request. Once used token will get blacklisted.

So even if your client issues multiple requests only first one will be accepted. Others can throw error `409 Conflict`. Once first request is processed new API token will be send back along with response, may be in headers.

Your client will have to keep updating the token from each response. If you are using AngularJS at client thats pretty easy using [interceptors](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)